# Can pinescript indicators be used in tradingview screeners?

Tags: filter, pine-script, indicator

I decided to write a custom indicator using pinescript to test out my trading strategy.

I can see if ndicator results on the current symbol open on my chart.

However, it would be effective if the indicator can be used to filter stocks or fx pairs using the trading view screeners. I don’t know if it is possible?

I tried to contact tradingview via email but got no replies yet also the same on the in app chatrooms and discussion boards.

The only last option I have is to get an answer from an experienced pinescript programmer and user of tradingview on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own screener using pinescript. You cannot connect your script to Tradingview's screener.

To create your own screener, you are going to need to request data from other assets by using the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

Please note that, you can only have 40 *security* calls in your script. And if you want to scan multiple timeframes, your screener will be VERY limited.